# Dropdown menu show text on hover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, hover

I got a little dropdown menu : [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4FfBMAwqmh)

Now my problem is that i cant get the onhover text to work, i want to have text apearing next to the menu whenever you hover over the icon, so you get a small text to show what you are clicking on, for example next to the home icon, i would like to have text appearing 'home', preferably not as after content.

here is an example of what i want: [example](http://lab.alexcican.com/account_menu/)

[image: IMG]

I really hope someone can help me out with this one, if I'm not clear enough please tell me how to make myself clear.

Comment: the thing you want to do is more complicated sorry

Comment: for simple drop down you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/733v8p7x/ your is complicated than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might heard of **CSS Tooltips**. Here is how you can make one of yours.

You can use `data-*` attribute to create such tooltips with only css3 capabilities. You need to change your markup little bit or i would say you need to add `data-*` attribute to your `li` elemetns:

```
<div class="menu">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-menu dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu arrow_box">
      <li data-tooltip="Info">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-info hover-btn" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-tooltip="Cubes">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-cubes hover-btn" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-tooltip="paint-brush">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-paint-brush hover-btn" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-tooltip="paper-plane">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane hover-btn" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and you need to have this css:

```
.dropdown-menu>li{position:relative;}
.dropdown-menu>li[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
   content: attr(data-tooltip);
   position: absolute;
   left: 40px;
   top: 10px;
   min-width: 75px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   border-radius: 2px;
   background: white;
   padding: 3px;
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 11px;
   box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

### [Bootply in action.](http://www.bootply.com/kFQ7vRlRPk)

Comment: Thats pretty much what i did indeed, unfortunatly i saw you answer to late, still gonna mark it as answer :) here is my [solution](http://www.bootply.com/uICA8UOGjD)

Comment: was waiting for someone say about css tooltips, so that's when i posted this answer.

Comment: i thought is was different but i tried it in her solution i added title and it is also working. just like the fiddle i posted

Comment: @Pekka absolutely that depends if you want to use attribute like title or anyother, but i prefer to use data attributes.

Comment: Sorry posted the wrong link, here is my working [solution](http://www.bootply.com/o4c7DUIgQt)

Answer (score 0):

use title="your title" if image then use alt="your title" which you want to show as tooltip

```
 <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-info hover-btn" title="info"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-cubes hover-btn" title="your title"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
```

Comment: OP wants a more complicated one see the link so you can view it as well

Comment: is it possible to style that ?

Comment: Better you use ':after' in css for li to show the tooltip

Comment: Yes you can use jquery tooltip...it will show styled tooltip

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a tooltip. I prefer [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos), but there are plenty of other options available.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').tooltipster();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The *tooltip*, you've referred in your **Source**, is being created by using `text-indent`, that means

1. they've created *icons* by using *pseudo elements* as `::after` OR `::before`
2. Further they've used tooltip texts as actual text as
   `<a href="" title="Account">Account</a>` and on `::hover`

   `nav a:hover {
      text-indent: 0px;
    }` they've reset the `text-indent: 0px;` and displayed that text as tooltip by giving that look n feel.

However you're using *font-awesome* and that trick won't work in your case. You either go with the default tooltip OR use *jQuery* plugins like [**Powertip**](http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip) by simply defining `title` as:

```
       <a href="#" title="text 0">
          <i class="fa fa-info hover-btn"></i>
        </a>
```

Further use plugin as:

```
   $('.dropdown-menu>li a').powerTip({
     placement: 'e'});
```

Here's  a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/rk6of925/2),

you can easily customize  UI of this tooltip, try using this, hope that will do the trick for you.